# Extract all links from Web page(Web crawler)

Tags: c#, asp.net, extract

I Want to develope an app I give Urls of specific website to it,and it extract all links from that Web page.
Here the web page that I want to give it's Url to my app,is developed by Asp.net and contains a Search buttom ,a GridView for showing the result and a DataPager ,and GridView contains HyperLinkField control for binding to the search's result.

When I click the Search buttom of the goal page the page is postbacked and show search result by GridView without changing the url of the page.

For example if search result have 500 records and datapager.PageSize=10 then we have 50 pages.

Now I want to know is it possible to extract all 500 links that binded to Gridview at once with my app,except opening all 50 pages and extract any page one by one with my app?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248411/get-all-links-on-html-page
Look at the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse ASP.NET page with postbacks :

> [Parse a .Net Page with Postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245782/parse-a-net-page-with-postbacks)
>   http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57101-website-scraping-and-postback/

Answer (score 3):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the best tool I have found for scraping URLs.

Your question is much broader (you seem to be asking how to write the entire app).  I suggest you start by reading about HTML Agility Pack, try some of the examples to scrape links from a page, then ask more specific questions if you're stuck on how to proceed.