# simulate javascript doPostBack using java to parse the result html

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, call, dopostback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse a .Net Page with Postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245782/parse-a-net-page-with-postbacks)

I have a web site I want to parse (it belongs to my client so no copyrights or so are a problem ). It has many links I want to call and parse the html returned. But those links are actually `doPostBack` javascript calls. So is there any way I can create such a call through Java and get the result html?

website:  **http://myclient.something/ProductCatalog.aspx?family=20**

javascript call:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$wpmMain$wp1312556404$wp432345009$tvwCatalog','sBLG')"
```

How can I simulate that javascript call?

Comment: If, as I surmise, this submits an HTTP POST request, then you may have a look at Apache's HTTPClient.

Comment: I tried with firefox plugin "Tamper Data" to see what it posts and I saw around 10 parameters. I put them in url parameters and it didn't work.

Comment: What if you posted the code you used?